# Sending MMS through CiviCRM?

Tags: sms, civisms

My org recently integrated Twilio with CiviCRM and while we're excited to start using something for SMS that's connected to the database, it doesn't look like we'll be able to send multimedia (MMS) pictures, etc. through the system.

I've looked through the documentation, and there is plenty of SMS but nothing that I can find on MMS or sending multimedia via the service. I did find this older ticket that discussed wanting to use the CiviSMS option to send QR codes and it noted that Twilio at the time didn't include MMS. With the updates to the Twilio platform to allow for MMS, are there ways to integrate (or update) the CiviCRM code to allow for MMS?

Related ticket on MMS through CiviCRM (~abt. 4 years old) [Send QR code via SMS?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/31595)

Answer (score 3):

I think there'd be some work required for this. In addition to updating the civi core forms to handle pics, the twilio integration hasn't really been updated in years, so it wouldn't support pics either at the moment.

Comment: ... but in principle, no reason why an updated version of Twilio integration couldn't support MMS.  Just needs people to sponsor & do it.

Answer (score 1):

an other option would be to use Whatsapp. I saw there's a beginning of an integration. And there's no cost per message. I'm thinking of Whatsapp as a good alternative to e-mail that people just don't read any more (not speaking for those who just don't use e-mails at all).